# Rails commands not working on raspberry pi though it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raspberry-pi

I've been setting up a server on my Raspberry Pi but for some reason when I SSH into the pi I can use the rails commands and start the Rails server but whenever I go into the terminal of the Pi itself it says:

```
bash: rails: command not found
```

Does someone know how to fix this? How can I make the rails command possible on the Pi terminal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try doing bash -l and then run your rails command.

Comment: Maybe its permission issue, the user you are using to ssh in raspbeerry Pi server should have access/permission to ruby path folder. So first try running rails/ruby commands in Rasberry Pi terminal by switching the user(user with which you ssh)

Comment: @HugoFarji this works but only temporarily, when I restart the pi I have to run the command again to make it work.

Comment: @SumeetMasih They are the same user

Comment: Lets try to debug, first run `rails -v` on PI terminal (with the user you are trying to ssh), and let us know the output.

Comment: When I cd into my rails app directory it `rails -v` gives `Could not find rake-11.3.0 in any of the sources run bundle install to install missing gems`. Then `bundle install` also gives an error `activesupport-5.0.0.1. requires ruby version >= 2.2.2, which is incompatible with the current version. ruby 2.1.5p273`

Answer (score 0):

rails should be in your $PATH variable

You can get the current PATH variable by typing echo $PATH

Here's my result

```
➜  angular git:(master) ✗ echo $PATH
/home/username/.rbenv/shims:/home/username/.rbenv/bin:/home/username/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin~
```

[How to Change PATH variable](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm)

Comment: This is currently in my PATH
`/home/pi/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/pi/.rbenv/shims:/home/pi/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/.rvm/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/bin`

but it still doesn't work for some reason